# How to get both mobile and desktop score with PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I'm trying to get page speed score for both: desktop and mobile and then pass them to #pgscore && #pgscorem inputs.

Problem is that at the end of script I get always var device == 'mobile'. It looks like it skips for loop. Any idea how could I fix it?

```
for (var r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
var API_KEY = 'mykey';
var device = '';

switch (r) {
    case 0: device='desktop'; break; 
    case 1: device='mobile'; break;
};  
alert(device);
var URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com' + '&strategy=' + device;

var API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?';
var CHART_API_URL = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?';


var callbacks = {}


function runPagespeed() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  var query = [
    'url=' + URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR,
    'callback=runPagespeedCallbacks',
    'key=' + API_KEY,
  ].join('&');
  s.src = API_URL + query;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, null);
}


function runPagespeedCallbacks(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    var errors = result.error.errors;
    for (var i = 0, len = errors.length; i < len; ++i) {
      if (errors[i].reason == 'badRequest' && API_KEY == 'yourAPIKey') {
        alert('Please specify your Google API key in the API_KEY variable.');
      } else {

        alert(errors[i].message);
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  for (var fn in callbacks) {
    var f = callbacks[fn];
    if (typeof f == 'function') {
      callbacks[fn](result);
    }
  }
}

setTimeout(runPagespeed, 0);


callbacks.displayPageSpeedScore = function(result) {
  var score = result.score;
```

Function countinues down there. Problem is here... Why I can't get variable device == 'desktop' first and then in second for loop 'mobile'? I get always 'mobile'.

```
switch (device) {
        case 'desktop': $('#pgscore').val(score); break; 
        case 'mobile': $('#pgscorem').val(score); break;
    };


 };



};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I need only score, I'm using php

```
$jsonurl="https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=$url&locale=pl_pl&$key"; 
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);  
  $json_output = json_decode($json, true); 
  /* print_r(array_values($json_output));*/
  echo $json_output['score'];
```